# Is it necessary for a Windows Server 2008 R2 to join a domain so that its IIS can communicate correctly?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 that is not join to any domain.

I have developed an web application that will display the domain name and the username on the server itself.

However, when I publish my web application to IIS, it always fail and display different types of error messages (because I change settings such as `Enabled ASP.NET Impersonation`, `Disable Anonymous Authentication`, `Set Application Pool to Classic` and so on)

So, I was wondering if it is necessary for the Server to join in a domain so that I can reduce any unnecessary error message and be able to zoom into the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is throwing errors due to configuration changes you've made to IIS, then joining an AD domain isn't going to help you.

You'll just need to buckle down, read through the error messages, and start your troubleshooting process.

Comment: Are there any good guides on how to setup a IIS and the different configuration required for different scenarios and purpose? (that you can recommend)

Comment: Sorry, no recommendations here.

Comment: Agreed, this is a config and code issue.  What kind of application have you developed (recently) that requires you to make all of those config changes.  None of them should be needed.